# Get author picture from blog entry

Tags: templates, liferay, liferay-6, velocity

I am creating a template for an ADT (Application Display Templates) which is a blog post and i want to show the picture of the author.

How I can do it?

I am using `liferay 6.2 ce ga6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the user object for the user in question (UserServiceUtil) and then use the get portrait method. You will need the themeDisplay object for that.

Comment: i tried this way but isnt working :( `#set ($userService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil"))
    #set ($authorPic = $userService.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)) <img src="$authorPic"/>`

Comment: the Util is not a service it's just a wrapper. you need to search for com.liferay.portal.service.User‌​LocalService and better for com.liferay.portal.service.User‌Service so that you don't expose access to all users

Comment: Still not working :( `#set ($userService = $UserLocalService.getUser($curEntry.userId))
    #set ($authorPic = $userService.getPortraitURL(themeDisplay)) <img src="$authorPic"/>`

Comment: then try to do some test print. Print the user Id, something from the theme display ...

Comment: i can only show the current logged user from theme display.

Comment: now im trying this way but still not working `#set($userConstants = $portal.getClass().forName("com.liferay.portal.model.UserConstants"))

#set($portraitUrl = $userConstants.getPortraitURL($request.theme-display.path-image, $user.male, $user.portraitId, $user.userUuid))`

Answer (score 0):

## Roundabout Solution

Based off the comment history above it looks like you still do not have this working.  One solution would be to import the Liferay UI taglib into your ADT and then us `<liferay-ui:user-display />` tag.

```
<#assign liferay_ui = taglibLiferayHash["/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-ui.tld"] />

<@liferay_ui.user-display markupView="lexicon" showUserDetails="false" showUserName="false" userId=userId userName=userName >
```

That will be equivalent to

```
<liferay-ui:user-display
        markupView="lexicon"
        showUserDetails="false"
        showUserName="false"
        userId="${userId}"
        userName="${userName}"
/>
```

One caveat I want to point out - in the JSP / JSTL example above I have used `${}` inside a double quote to represent an EL variable.  You cannot include the double quote in the ADT version because it will be represented as a string literal